# Direct Share Targets not showing in share chooser

Tags: java, android

I am looking at creating a tasker plugin that allows users to customize their direct share targets on android 6.0. I have everything up and running like the documentation explains, but they do not show up. All help is much appreciated.

Here is manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".receiver.ShareReceiver"
        android:label="Test"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_labels">

        <intent-filter android:label="Test" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_labels">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.service.chooser.chooser_target_service"
            android:value=".ui.DirectShareService" />

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ui.ActivityIconSelector"
        android:label="Icon Selector">

    </activity>
```

Here is DirectShareService:

```
public class DirectShareService extends ChooserTargetService {

    public SharedPreferences directShare;
    public List<ChooserTarget> items;
    public int numberOfItems;
    public String title;
    public String iconText;

    @Override
    public List<ChooserTarget> onGetChooserTargets(ComponentName targetActivityName, IntentFilter matchedFilter) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        return getItems(targetActivityName, intent);
    }

    public List<ChooserTarget> getItems(ComponentName targetActivityName, Intent intent) {
        directShare = getSharedPreferences("Direct Share", 0);
        numberOfItems = getRightAmount(directShare.getInt("Items", 0));
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfItems; i++) {
            switch (i) {
                case 1:
                    title = directShare.getString("OneTitle", "Not Set");
                    iconText = directShare.getString("OneIcon", "Not Set");
                    items.add(getTarget(title, iconText, "", i, targetActivityName, intent));
                    break;
                case 2:
                    title = directShare.getString("TwoTitle", "Not Set");
                    iconText = directShare.getString("TwoIcon", "Not Set");
                    items.add(getTarget(title, iconText, "", i, targetActivityName, intent));
                    break;
                case 3:
                    title = directShare.getString("ThreeTitle", "Not Set");
                    iconText = directShare.getString("ThreeIcon", "Not Set");
                    items.add(getTarget(title, iconText, "", i, targetActivityName, intent));
                    break;
                case 4:
                    title = directShare.getString("FourTitle", "Not Set");
                    iconText = directShare.getString("FourIcon", "Not Set");
                    items.add(getTarget(title, iconText, "", i, targetActivityName, intent));
                    break;
            }
        }
        return items;
    }

public ChooserTarget getTarget(String title, String icon, String command, int num, ComponentName targetActivityName, Intent intent) {
        if (icon.equals("Not Set")) {
            return new ChooserTarget(title, Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.ic_action_labels), num, targetActivityName, intent.getExtras());
        } else
            return new ChooserTarget(title, Icon.createWithContentUri(icon), num, targetActivityName, intent.getExtras());
    }
```

Comment: What `<activity>` has the `<meta-data>` element for `android.service.chooser.chooser_target_service`? Also, how are you testing this?

Comment: @CommonsWare I just put the main activity as it for now while I tested to see if it worked (updated the post to show it). I am testing this by going into google+ and sharing the post.

Comment: "I just put the main activity as it for now while I tested to see if it worked" -- AFAIK, `ChooserTargetService` is only used for `ACTION_SEND` and perhaps `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`. Is "the main activity" implementing one of those?

Comment: @CommonsWare it was not, but I just changed it to have ACTION_SEND and they still did not show up. I also just updated the post with the method getTarget, one thing to note is it asks for a bundle of extras when creating the target which is different than what I saw in the documentation

Comment: "I just changed it to have ACTION_SEND and they still did not show up" -- did you change your testing approach, to do something that would cause this activity to appear in the chooser? Forget the `ChooserTargetService` for a bit. Just get the activity to appear in the chooser. Then, add the `<meta-data>` back in. FWIW, [this sample app of mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Intents/FauxSenderMNC) worked the last time I tried it, a few months ago when 6.0 shipped.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am going to mess around with it a little bit, one discrepancy I found is that you created a new component name while I used the targetActivityName. I just added a different activity with the intent filter as Action SEND but it does not appear in the regular part of the share menu. So I guess there is something wrong there? Edit: I just added the extra intent filters and it now shows up in the regular menu. I am now going to try and add the meta data

Comment: "So I guess there is something wrong there?" -- I am not completely following your current app's state, so I'll give you a qualified "maybe". :-) That's why I suggested starting with a simple no-direct-share `ACTION_SEND` scenario, get that working, then augment it with direct-share. If you then want to play around with seeing if things other than `ACTION_SEND` trigger the direct-share logic, you at least have a solid foundation for going forward.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just copied off your app manifest for the share reciever activity and it now shows up in the regular share menu. I added the meta data but it still did not show up in the direct share menu.

Comment: OK, use log statements or breakpoints to see if you're getting called, check LogCat to see if there are interesting messages around the point of the chooser appearing, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok, I added logs and it turns out the service is never being called on, do you know what could be the cause?

Comment: `ShareReceiver` is an odd name for an `<activity>`. Otherwise, nothing leaps out at me as to being the source of your difficulty, sorry.

Comment: Huh, I guess what I will do is use your exact code and see if it works. If it does then who knows what would be going wrong.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just added your code exactly and it did not work. The menu still did not show up. This is starting to get very confusing.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I just ran my sample app now on a Nexus 5 running Android 6.0, and it works as expected. Try running my app on your test device. If it works, try uninstalling and reinstalling your app. If mine does not work on your device, then something else is afoot.

Comment: ok how do I download your whole app? I will solely run your app. I am running a nexus 5x on 6.0.1 and these are not showing up. Thanks for your help, will comment here if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You should remind with this constructor:

```
public ChooserTarget(CharSequence title, Icon icon, float score,
        ComponentName componentName, @Nullable Bundle intentExtras);
```

-score: ranking score for this target between 0.0f and 1.0f, inclusive

In the constructor, score will be checked:

```
if (score > 1.f || score < 0.f) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Score " + score + " out of range; "
                + "must be between 0.0f and 1.0f");
    }
```

So please do not fill the score by 'i' values in your code!